# PostgreSQL query is very slow after disk re-size

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

I am using PostgreSQL DB for my production database and I have recently resized my production server's disk volume.

And i have noticed query on a particular table (~10K records) is extremely slow,

```
    EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers, timing) SELECT count(id) FROM markets_sales WHERE volume>0;
                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1844791.17..1844791.18 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=79842.776..79842.777 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2329 read=1842313
   ->  Seq Scan on markets_sales  (cost=0.00..1844782.68 rows=3399 width=4) (actual time=8139.929..79842.043 rows=6731 loops=1)
         Filter: (volume > '0'::double precision)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 4523
         Buffers: shared hit=2329 read=1842313
 Planning time: 0.110 ms
 Execution time: 79842.809 ms
```

But the similar query on another table (~2K records) is perfect.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(id) FROM markets_volume WHERE percent>0;
                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1368.87..1368.88 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.866..1.866 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on markets_volume  (cost=0.00..1365.59 rows=1312 width=4) (actual time=0.023..1.751 rows=1313 loops=1)
         Filter: (h24_change > '0'::double precision)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1614
 Planning time: 0.093 ms
 Execution time: 1.903 ms
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I'm not really fluent on reading postgres execution plans, but it looks like you don't have an index on `percent`? That'd be the first step in speeding things up.

Comment: i doubt the issue is with indexing, the table has only 10K records .. and is taking ~80 seconds .. i run similar query on a table with 95 million records, it takes only 100 s.

Comment: @shawn i have indexed percent field and query is faster if i use 'percent' field .. But it is still extremely slow for a non indexed field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - i have edited with buffers and timing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Great that worked, looks like the memory layout issue. You can add the same as answer, will accept it. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of buffers (=blocks read from disk) is way too high for only 11254 rows.

So most probably your tables is [bloated](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat). This can be rectified using:

```
vacuum full analyze markets_sales;
```

Note that the statement will require and exclusive lock on the table (thus blocking any read or write access).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PostgreSQL's slow query log. In a default configuration the slow query log is inactive. You should turn it on from postgresql.conf file. It gives you more detail what the problem is. Then you can take an action about the problem.